# Indy TIdTCPServer TIdTCPClient data exchange

Tags: delphi, indy

I spent some time to write a simple application to exchange data between `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPClient`. But now I'm stuck.
I can send data from `TIdTCPClient` to `TIdTCPServer` and can process this.
But have no idea and official documentation didn't give any clue how to send data from `TIdTCPServer` and process it on `TIdTCPClient`. Please advise.

My code is simple:

main application:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses ClientThread, ServerThread;

var
  ClientThread: TClientThread;
  ServerThread: TServerThread;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var OutputDebugString:string;
begin
  ServerThread:=TServerThread.Create(False);
  ServerThread.Priority:=tpNormal;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ClientThread:=TClientThread.Create(False);
  ClientThread.Priority:=tpNormal;
 end;
```

Server Thread:

```
unit ServerThread;

interface

uses
  Classes, System.SysUtils, IdContext, IdTCPServer, TaskQue;

type
  TServerThread = class(TThread) //MyThread - заданное нами имя потока.
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

 TServer = class(TObject)
   IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
   procedure IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
   procedure IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
   { Private declarations }
   constructor Create;
  public
  end;

type
TDatagram = record
    Proto: byte;
    Command: word;
    DataSize: word;
    data: array [0..4096] of byte;
  end;

var
  Server : TServer;

implementation

uses YouFreedom;

constructor TServer.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;
 IdTCPServer1 := TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
 IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Clear;
// IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort := 10001;
  try
    with idTCPserver1.Bindings.Add do
    begin
      IP := '127.0.0.1';
      Port := 10001;
    end;
  finally     //dirty hack
      idTCPserver1.Bindings.Add.IP := '127.0.0.1';
      idTCPserver1.Bindings.Add.Port := 10002;
  end;
// idTCPserver1.Bindings.Add.Port:=10001;
// IdTCPServer1.Bindings.Add.IP := '127.0.0.1';
 IdTCPServer1.Tag := 0;
 IdTCPServer1.TerminateWaitTime := 5000;
 IdTCPServer1.OnConnect := IdTCPServer1Connect;
 IdTCPServer1.OnExecute := IdTCPServer1Execute;
end;

procedure TServer.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);

var
  MIRec: TDatagram;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  size: integer;
  i:integer;
  recieve:byte;
  respstream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
   msRecInfo:= TMemoryStream.Create;
   AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadStream(msRecInfo, -1, false);
   msRecInfo.Position := 0;
   msRecInfo.ReadBuffer(MIRec, msRecInfo.size);
   Form1.addtoque := '1';
//   Form1.s := inttostr(MIRec.Proto)
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('Proto = ' + inttostr(MIRec.Proto));
  finally
   msRecInfo.Free
  end;
end;

procedure TServer.IdTCPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
//AContext.Connection.Socket.WriteLn('hello');
end;

procedure TServerThread.Execute;
begin
 Server := TServer.Create;
 try
  Server.IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
 except
      on E: Exception do
       // OutputDebugString(PChar(E.ToString)); //do something
      end;
end;


end.
```

Client thread:

```
unit ClientThread;

interface

uses
  Classes, IdTCPClient;

type
  TClientThread = class(TThread) //MyThread - заданное нами имя потока.
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

 TClient = class(TObject)
   IdTCPClient1: TIdTCPClient;
//   procedure IdTCPClient1OnWorkBegin(AContext: TIdContext);
  private
   { Private declarations }
   constructor Create;
  public
  end;

implementation

type
TDatagram = record
    Proto: byte;
    Command: word;
    DataSize: word;
    data: array [0..4096] of byte;
  end;

var
  ClientConnection : TClient;

constructor TClient.Create;
begin
 inherited Create;
 IdTCPClient1 := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);
// IdTCPClient1.ReuseSocket := rsOSDependent;
 IdTCPClient1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
 IdTCPClient1.Port := 10001;
// IdTCPClient1.OnWorkBegin := IdTCPClient1OnWorkBegin;
end;

procedure TClientThread.Execute;
var
  MIRec: TDatagram;
  msRecInfo: TMemoryStream;
  i,k:integer;
  Client1: TIdTCPClient;
  recieve:byte;
  respstream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  ClientConnection := TClient.Create;
  ClientConnection.IdTCPClient1.Connect;
  for k := 1 to 5 do begin

  if ClientConnection.IdTCPClient1.Connected then begin
{   MIRec.DataSize := 64;
   for i:=0 to MIRec.DataSize do
    MIRec.data[i] := i;
   for i:=129 to 4096 do MIRec.data[i] := 0;}
   MIRec.Proto := 1;
   MIRec.Command :=1;
  try
    msRecInfo := TMemoryStream.Create;
    msRecInfo.WriteBuffer(MIRec, SizeOf(MIRec));
    msRecInfo.Position := 0;
    ClientConnection.IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write(msRecInfo, msRecInfo.Size, true);
  finally
    msRecInfo.Free;
  end;
  end;
  end
 end;




end.
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misusing `Bindings.Add()` and thus are creating *3* bindings:

```
127.0.0.1:10001
127.0.0.1:0
0.0.0.0:10002
```

I'm sure that is NOT what you really wanted.

As for your question - it depends on what your server needs to do.

If the server *only* responds to client commands then you can write a response directly in the `OnExecute` event after reading a command.  A client can read the response immediately after sending a command.  This is the typical usage.

If the server *only* sends unsolicited data to clients, then you can `Lock()` the server's `Contexts` list when needed, locate the desired connection and write to it, then `Unlock()` the list.  A client will have to be reading asynchrously, such as in a thread, to read these messages.

If the server needs to do *both*, then this gets tricky.  The best option is to implement a thread-safe outbound queue for each client, then you can put unsolicited data into the queue and have the `OnExecute` send the contents of the queue when it is safe to do so.

I have posted examples of all these in the Embarcadero and Indy forums many times before.  Search around.

Comment: This code is just a prototype, so i didt pay too much attention to the safety and resource management. And you are right finally i want a que to answer clients asyncronous way. And stuck with events on both server and client side to send data back to client. However i will try to search.